# uncheck radio button on button click using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, button, radio-button

This simple thing i'm not able to do and me new to angularjs.. I have two radio buttons(suppose named female and male) with same ng-model and 1 reset button.

When i tap reset button i want both radio button to be unchecked.

I tried many things but did not work.

simple example will be good.

thanks

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" ng-model="sex"
           value="male">male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" ng-model="sex"
           value="female">female<br>
    sex={{sex}}<br>
    <button ng-click="sex=null">Reset</button>
</body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS `input type=radio` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).